# Insert into array specific strings from text file

Tags: c++

`ArticlesDataset.txt` file contains all the metadata information of documents. `unigramCount` contains all unique words and their number of occurrences for each document. There are 1500 publications recorded in the txt file. Here is an example entry for a document:

```
  {"creator":["Romain Allais","Julie Gobert"],
   "datePublished":"2018-05-30",
   "docType":"article",
   "doi":"10.1051\/mattech\/2018010",
   "id":"ark:\/\/27927\/phz10hn2bh3",
   "isPartOf":"Mat\u00e9riaux & Techniques",
   "issueNumber":"5-6",
   "language":["eng"],
   "outputFormat":["unigram","bigram","trigram"],
   "pageCount":7,
   "pagination":"pp. null-null",
   "provider":"portico",
   "publicationYear":2018,
   "publisher":"EDP Sciences",
   "sequence":3.0,
   "tdmCategory":["Applied sciences -Engineering"],
   "title":"Environmental assessment of PSS",
   "url":"http:\/\/doi.org\/10.1051\/mattech\/2018010",
   "volumeNumber":"105",
   "wordCount":4446,
   "unigramCount":{"others":1,"air":1,"networks,":1,"conventional":1,"IEEE":1}}
```

My purpose is to pull out the unigram counts for each document and store them in a suitable array. How can I do it by using fstream library?

How can i improve below code to reach my goal.

```
  std::string dummy;
    std::ifstream data("PublicationsDataSet.txt");
    while (data.good())
    {
        getline(data, dummy, ',');

    }
```

Comment: Can we see some codes that you tried writing?

Comment: I'd recommend using a JSON library for this, such as [nlohmann/json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam i added the code .

Comment: @rturrado i can't use third-party libraries

Comment: I gave a full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815367/c-how-to-get-spesific-values-from-a-json-like-text-file/70815714#70815714. But I would be really interested in what you are allowed to use and what not. Then I would give you the appropriate answer. So which C++ elements are you allowed to use and which not?

Answer (score 1):

your question delves in two different topics, one is parsing the data and the other into storing it in memory.

To the first point the answer is, you'll need a parser, you either write one which will involve a syntax parser to convert each "key words" into tokens, for then an interpreter to compile them into a data object based on the token parameter the data is preceded or succeeded eg:

- '[' = start an array, every values after this are part of the array
- ']' = end of the an array, return to previous parsing state
- ':' = separate key and values, left hand side is key, right hand side is value
- ...

this is a fine exercise to sharpen one's skills but way too arduous and with potential never-ending-bug-fixing road, as recommended also by other comments finding an already made library is probably the easier road on a time pinch or on a project time crunching scenario.

Another thing to point out, plain arrays in c++ are size fixed, so mostly likely since you are parsing the values you'll probably use std::vectors, which allow insertion, and once you are done processing the file and really intend to send the data back as an array you can do that directly from the object

```
std::vector<YourObjectType> parsedObject;
char* arr = new char[parsedObject.size()];
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), arr);
```

this is a psudo code, lots of things will depend on the implementation, but it gives the idea.

A starting point to write a parse is this article goes in great details on how it works and it's components, mind you every parser implements it's own language (yes just like c++ and other languages, are all parsed) so you'll need to expand on the concept with your commands

[expression parser](https://unclechromedome.org/c++-tutorials/expression-parser/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified solution of what you could do using `std::regex`:

- Read the lines of a stream (`std::cin` in this case) one by one.
- Check if the line contains a `unigramCount` element.
- If that's the case, walk the different entries within the `unigramCount` element.

About the regular expressions used:

1. `"unigramCount":{}`, allowing:

- zero or more whitespaces basically everywhere, and
- zero or more characters within the braces.

2. `"<key>":<value>`, where:

- `<key>` is one or more characters other than a double quote,
- `<value>` is one or more digits, and
- you could have whitespaces at both sides of the `:`.

A good data structure for storing your `unigramCount` entries could be a `std::map`.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/5bjqh4Pq6)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <map>
#include <regex>  // regex_match, regex_search, sregex_iterator
#include <string>  // stoi

int main()
{
    std::string line{};
    std::map<std::string, int> unigram_counts{};
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        const std::regex unigram_count_pattern{R"(^\s*\"unigramCount\"\s*:\s*\{.*\}\s*$)"};
        if (std::regex_match(line, unigram_count_pattern))
        {
            const std::regex entry_pattern{R"(\"([^\"]+)\"\s*:\s*([0-9]+))"};
            for (auto entry_it{std::sregex_iterator(line.cbegin(), line.cend(), entry_pattern)};
                entry_it != std::sregex_iterator{};
                ++entry_it)
            {
                auto matches{*entry_it};
                auto& key{matches[1]};
                auto& value{matches[2]};
                unigram_counts[key] = std::stoi(value);
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto& [key, value] : unigram_counts)
    {
        std::cout << "'" << key << "' : " << value << "\n";
    }
}

// Outputs:
//
//   'IEEE' : 1
//   'air' : 1
//   'conventional' : 1
//   'networks,' : 1
//   'others' : 1
```