# C++ how to get spesific values from a JSON-like text file?

Tags: c++

[image]

I have a .txt file that contains hundreds of book information. (The image shown is only one of them, it has multiple line of same info with different datas in the same .txt file) I only want to check for "unigramCount" values and find the top 3 most frequent words. So the program should look for each word in unigramCount lines, and increase the number by the number in front of the words. Store them in an array or linked list, and at the end tell the most frequent 3 words.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: take some library rapidJson or nlohmannJson

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: use a JSON library.

Comment: Please see one potential solution below

Comment: I wonder, how any of the question closers can have the idea that the linked answer can be of any help. What a nonsense. Check the linked question and answer with a boost::property_tree. That is really shocking . . .  If at all the use https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is a so called structured text file, like xml or json.

A [grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) can define the language (structure) of the file. And if we look at the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy) classification , then we have here a so called “Context free language”, which can and should be analyzed with a typical [push down automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) or a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

But you mentioned that you “only want to check the unigram count”. This is crying for a [Chomsky hierarchy 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#Type-3_grammars) [regular grammer](http://Regular%20grammar) which can be implemented with a [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Please note: Normally you cannot use regular expressions, because they cannot identify nested structures. For example. If you have nested opening and closing braces, a regular expression cannot work. To say it simple. A regular expression cannot count.

Anyway, because of the simplicity of the given file, we can survive with pattern matching by employing regular expressions.

The good thing is that C++ supports regular expressions with its [regex library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

But even so, we cannot find a solution with a single regular expression. We will use a 3 step approach by

1. Match all lines that contain unigram data
2. Iterate over the above matched lines and extract the word/count pairs
3. Split the word count pairs into word and count

(The regexes can be tested in any online regex tester like [here](https://regex101.com/)).

And if we have this, we will use a associative [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), like a [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), if ordering matters, or a [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) if speed matters for counting. The order is meant for the words and not the counts.

Using maps is more or less the standard approach for counting items. The “key” is the word the we want to count. It is unique. And the associated vale is the count.

Both maps have a convenient [index operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). You can put the key (in our case the instance of a unigram word) in brackets `[]`, and if the word is already there, the index operator will return a reference to the associated value.

If the word in the index is not yet in the map, it will be created and the value will be initialized in our case to 0. An, again a reference to this value will be returned. So in any case the result will be a reference to the counter value, which we can then increment.

Cool.

But, because of the nature of associative containers, you cannot sort them. So, we need to copy the resulting word/count pairs in a 2nd container.

And there perfectly fitting function for that in the CPP algorithm library. The [std::partial_sort_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy). With that we can find the top 3 and copy them to the resulting `std::vector`.

So, we will heavily use the existing and advanced C++ functionality to implement the solution with a few lines of code.

There are many many different possible solutions. One example is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <map>

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// Create aliases. Save typing work and make code more readable
using Pair = std::pair<std::string, unsigned int>;
// Standard approach for counter
//using Counter = std::unordered_map<Pair::first_type, Pair::second_type>;
using Counter = std::map<Pair::first_type, Pair::second_type>;
// Sorted values will be stored in a vector
using Top = std::vector<Pair>;
// ------------------------------------------------------------

// Regexes
const std::regex unigramLineIdentifierRegex{R"(\"unigramCount\":\{(.*)\})"};
const std::regex unigramCountRegex{ R"((\"[a-zA-Z ,]+\"\:\d+)+)" };
const std::regex wordAndCountRegex(R"(\"([a-zA-Z ,]+)\":(\d+))");

int main() {
    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream ifs{"text.txt"}; ifs) {

        // Read the complete textfile into a string
        std::string text(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), {});
        
        // Here we will count the words
        Counter counter{};

        // Now extract all lines containing the unigram line pattern into a std::vector
        std::vector unigramLine(std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), unigramLineIdentifierRegex), {});

        // For each of the found lines containg a unigram record
        for (const std::string& wordAndCount : unigramLine) {

            // Extract all word count pairs
            std::vector unigrams(std::sregex_token_iterator(wordAndCount.begin(), wordAndCount.end(), unigramCountRegex), {});

            // Go over all word/count strings and split them up
            for (const std::string unigram : unigrams) {

                // Find the word part and the count part
                std::smatch smWordAndCount{};
                if (std::regex_match(unigram, smWordAndCount, wordAndCountRegex)) {

                    // Increment the global counter
                    counter[smWordAndCount[1]] += std::stoi(smWordAndCount[2]);
                }
            }
        }
        // Here we will store the top 3
        Top top(3);

        // Copy and sort. Get only the biggest 3
        std::partial_sort_copy(counter.begin(), counter.end(), top.begin(), top.end(), [](const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) { return p1.second > p2.second; });

        // Debug output. Show the result´, the top3 on the screen
        for (const auto& [word, count] : top)
            std::cout << word << " \t--> " << count << '\n';
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n*** Error: Could not open source file\n\n";
}
```

Please be reminded. The regex solution is not the idiomatic correct approach.

And if the file is really JSON, then look at [this library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json)