# out of range error on top 10 frequent words project

Tags: c++, data-structures, memory-leaks, project, outofrangeexception

I was assigned a project to read a large text file of different articles, and print out the top 10 most frequent words, i managed to remove all unnecessary information from the file and print it into a string, for simplicity i put a small part the list of unigrams and their frequency in a text file (text2.txt), this is essentially the format in which all the unigrams are written:            "(unigram)":(it's frequency within that article),"(another unigram)":(it's frequency within that article)  and so on

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void something(string input, int sizeOfDoc, string unigrams[], int freq[]){
    char found;
    char last_found2;
    char last_found;
    char next_found;
    bool b = false;
    int pos = 0;
    string word;
    unsigned int u=0;
    unsigned int f=0;

    for(int x = 0; x<sizeOfDoc; x++){
        found = input.at(x);
        if(x==sizeOfDoc){
            next_found= '*';
        }else{next_found = input.at(x+1);}

        if(x==0){
            last_found = '*';
        }else{last_found = input.at(x-1);}

        if(x==0 || x==1){
            last_found2 = '*';
        }else{last_found2 = input.at(x-2);}

        if((last_found2  >= '1' && last_found2 <= '9') && last_found == ',' && found == '\"' &&  //
           (next_found >='a' && next_found <='z' || next_found >='A' && next_found <='Z')){      //finds first letter of unigram
            word = next_found; //a
        }
        else if((found >='a' && found <='z' || found >='A' && found <='Z') &&                     //
                (last_found >='a' && last_found <='z' || last_found >='A' && last_found <='Z')){  //finds middle of unigram
            word += found;  //b  abc word = "abc"
        }
        else if((last_found2 >='a' && last_found2 <='z' || last_found2 >='A' && last_found2 <='Z')  //
                && last_found =='"' && found == ':' && (next_found >= '1' && next_found <= '9')){   //finds frequency
            word += last_found2;  //adds last letter to word

            for(int i=0; i <= u; i++){    //
                if(word == unigrams[i]){  //
                    b = true;             //
                    pos = i;              //checks for duplicate, if found, returns position to pos
                }
            }
            if (b==false){
                unigrams[u] = word;   //adds word to unigrams array
                freq[f] = next_found; //adds frequency to freq array
            }
            else if(b == true){     //
                freq[pos]=freq[f];  //increments frequency if duplicate found
            }
            f++;
            u++;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    string unigrams[1279];
    int freq[1279];

    string s;
    std::string newstring;
    ifstream file;                //
    file.open("text2.txt");       //
    while (!file.eof()) {         //
        getline(file, s);         //
        newstring += s + "\n";    //reads original text and inputs it into newstring
    }file.close();

    something(newstring, newstring.size(), unigrams, freq);  //calls function

    for (int x = 0; x <= 1278; x++) {  //
        cout << unigrams[x];           //prints unigrams to console
    }
}
```

when i run the code it throws

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 1278) >= this->size() (which is 1278)
```

i have tried using vectors instead of arrays with emplace_back, push_back, and directly assigning, all to no avail, there's much more to work on in the project, submission is tomorrow and the more i progress the more complex it gets ):

this is the text im using:

```
{"others":1,"air":1,"networks,":1,"conventional":1,"Environ.":1,"AHP":1,"Osterwalder,":1,"la":8,"Non-motorized":1,"(SHE).":1,"beer":1,"[7,8]":1,"provider":1,"futurible":1,"13(4),":1,"Agency":1,"24.":1,"concern":1,"eight":1,"facilitated":1,"2009":1,"review":1,"Car,":4,"viability.":1,"cycles":1,"contribute":1,"results,":1,"design":24,"CSIROPub.9780643094529,":1,"ecodesign":2,"reserves":1,"follow:":1,"sp\u00e9cifique":2,"(2017)[20,21,22].":1,"pp.":4,"Costs":1,"diversity":1,"In-depth":1,"Both":1,"\u2013":6,"Grenoble":1,"realistic":2,"Largepurchasecost:":1,"navale":1,"Est,":1,"petits":1,"Support":1,"eliminated":1,"relationship,":1,"progressed,":1,"Imnm":1,"significantly":2,"76":1,"Technical":1,"Tertre,":1,"(Fig.":1,"Freeman,":1,"(1.28>Ib":1,"IT":2,"defined":1,"maturity":1,"experimentation.":1,"review,":2,"interests":1,"tools":1,"Firm":3,"opportunities.":1,"behaviour":1,"2014":1,"fili\u00e8res":1,"feedback":3,"interviews":1,"60":1,"187":1,"d\u00e9fi":1,"strategies":3,"did":1,"Techniques":8,"In":8,"have":5,"issues.":1,"useful":1,"se":1,"QC,":1,"vision":1,"regarding":1,"take":4,"Brezet,":1,"such":2,"circulaire":1,"software":1,"parameter":9,"appliances":3,"wedging":1,"Prod.":6,"domains\u201d.":1,"typologie,":1,"D\u00e9veloppement":3,"real":1,"desACVcomparatives":1}}
```

its a sample of one list of unigrams and their frequencies, the formatting is horrible as you can see i had to create a million conditions to take out the words without running into issues caused by things like words with quotation marks within them, the original file has 1500 publications and this text is just a small part of one of them, thank you for reading this at least

Comment: `}else{next_found = input.at(x+1);}` is a bug. When `x` is `sizeOfDoc-1` you access  `input.at(sizeOfDoc);` which is one past the end of the string.

Comment: `if(x==sizeOfDoc){`  will never be true. You want to change that to `if (x == sizeOfDoc-1)` instead

Comment: @drescherjm thank you! you are a legend, i think you can imagine the faceplam after spending 6 hours straight trying to fix it

Comment: Your code is somehow complicated. See for example a full solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815367/c-how-to-get-spesific-values-from-a-json-like-text-file/70815714#70815714.  Do you have restriction to use C++ containers? Or, what are you allowed to use?

Comment: @ArminMontigny I am confined within just C++ and it's default libraries, im not allowed to use another language or external libraries, the assignment has the exact same screenshot as the one you linked, i tried reading your answer but if im being frank i didnt understand a single sentence, and the code is alien to me, i apologize for my naivety but our course is data structures and algorithms, we're supposed to be worrying about optimizing the running time (30% of the grade depends on that) by using hashtables and heap sort but we did not study anything about processing data of this sort

Comment: i realize that my function has a lot of errors but these were just the issues i could think ahead of since i couldnt run the code, i made many adjustments to it but it was still problematic and i ended up scrapping the whole thing and using a completely different approach, and am going to submit a code that just prints all the unigrams and all their frequencies separately, the task is simply too complex for second year computer engineering students, i genuinely appreciate your help though, thank you for taking the time (:

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is here, specifically because when you call input.at() the maximum argument should be sizeOfDoc - 1.

```
for(int x = 0; x<sizeOfDoc; x++){
    found = input.at(x);
    if(x==sizeOfDoc){
        next_found= '*';
    }else{next_found = input.at(x+1);}
```

If you consider the case where x == sizeOfDoc - 1, the last line shown will result in calling at with an argument of sizeOfDoc, which is too high.  To fix this, change

```
    if(x==sizeOfDoc){
```

to

```
    if(x==sizeOfDoc - 1){
```

Comment: yes that fixed that issue, thank you a lot!